# MooTools Form Request reverts values after submitting

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, mootools, request

I have a MooTools form request that is causing problems for me.

When the form is submitted, the values change back to the values they were when the form was generated.

```
var formRequest = new Form.Request(myFormValidator, dialogBox, {

    onSend: function(){
        dialogBox.setStyle('display','block');
        dialogBox.fade(1);
        dialogBox.set('html','Saving');

    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {

        dialogBox.setStyle('display','block');
        dialogBox.fade(1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Solution

After searching through the [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Request#Form-Request%3aconstructor) a little more thoroughly, I found the form resets itself by default. Go figure. There is a literal value `resetForm` that needs to be set to `false`.

```
var formRequest = new Form.Request(myFormValidator, dialogBox, {

    resetForm: false,
    onSend: function(){
        dialogBox.setStyle('display','block');
        dialogBox.fade(1);
        dialogBox.set('html','Saving');

    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {

        dialogBox.setStyle('display','block');
            dialogBox.fade(1);

    }
});
```

---

## The Explanation

The default seems counter-intuitive, at least in the context of an edit form. When you make changes to a record and save it, you would expect your changes to stay on screen, not change back.

**Example Form Field Behavior (resetForm:true)**

```
                Change                     Submit
Name: [ Bob ]     -->     Name: [ Bobby ]     -->     Name: [ Bob ]
```

**Example Form Field Behavior (resetForm:false)**

```
                Change                     Submit
Name: [ Bob ]     -->     Name: [ Bobby ]     -->     Name: [ Bobby ]
```

---

## The Original Intention of the Developers

So why is the default to clear the form? The only way I can make sense of it is in the context of a quick-entry form. After you fill out the form it would clear so you can enter another record quickly.

**Example Form Field Behavior (resetForm:true)**

```
                Change                     Submit
Name: [     ]     -->     Name: [ Bobby ]    -->     Name: [     ]
Name: [     ]     -->     Name: [ David ]    -->     Name: [     ]
Name: [     ]     -->     Name: [ Susan ]    -->     Name: [     ]
```

Comment: This is why Mootools sucks. They sneakily hid all the instructions on their 'documentation' pages where nobody would ever think to look.